# multi select query in php

Tags: php, sql

how can I select a list from my table that search on 2 rows like this query :

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE first_name and last_name LIKE '%$input%';
```

This doesn't work. i want to search in 2 columns in table...

Any idea ?
look at this example

```
user type in input : amin heydari and the first name in table is amin and 
last name is heydari. if i add 'and' in query: if user type 'a' page show 
list --> a in amin and a in heydari i want to show list if type amin 
heydari...
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM customer WHERE first_name LIKE '%$input%'; and last_name LIKE '%$input%';

Comment: Probably should be OR rather than AND in the OP and the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$input = explode(' ',trim($input));

if(count($input)==2){
   SELECT * FROM customer WHERE first_name LIKE '%$input[0]%' OR last_name LIKE '%$input[1]%';
}
if(count($input)==1){
   SELECT * FROM customer WHERE first_name LIKE '%$input[0]%' OR last_name LIKE '%$input[0]%';
}
if(count($input)>2){
   SELECT * FROM customer WHERE first_name LIKE '%$input[0]%' OR last_name LIKE '%$input[1]%';
}
```

Query will look like this:- https://eval.in/841836

Comment: A name is not always a or two or three words.

Comment: @emen  there are endless possibility then.